# SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported ▌How I can fix this?

Tags: python, pandas

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGZ1z.png)

```
   Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in 
1 # Aggregate by Type and Gender
----> 2 df_grouped_start = df_total.groupby(['Start Date', 'Start Station Name', 'Start Station Latitude','Start Station Longitude']).agg({'Trip Duration':{'Trip Duration Mean (s)':'mean'}, 'Bike ID':{'Total Rides':'count'}})
3 df_grouped_start.columns = df_grouped_start.columns.droplevel(0)
4 # Export the dataframe to a csv file
5 df_grouped_start.to_csv('data_output/start_date.csv')

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
943         func = maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
944
--> 945         result, how = aggregate(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
946         if how is None:
947             return result

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py in aggregate(obj, arg, *args, **kwargs)
580     elif is_dict_like(arg):
581         arg = cast(AggFuncTypeDict, arg)
--> 582         return agg_dict_like(obj, arg, _axis), True
583     elif is_list_like(arg):
584         # we require a list, but not an 'str'

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\aggregation.py in agg_dict_like(obj, arg, _axis)
738             # {'ra' : { 'A' : 'mean' }}
739             if isinstance(v, dict):
--> 740                 raise SpecificationError("nested renamer is not supported")
741             elif isinstance(selected_obj, ABCSeries):
742                 raise SpecificationError("nested renamer is not supported")

SpecificationError: nested renamer is not supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [named aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html#named-aggregation) with `**` for unpack dictionaries, because there are spaces in columns names:

```
df_grouped_start = (df_total.groupby(['Start Date', 'Start Station Name', 'Start Station Latitude','Start Station Longitude'])
                            .agg(**{'Trip Duration Mean (s)':('Trip Duration','mean'), 
                                   'Total Rides':('Bike ID','count')}))
df_grouped_start.to_csv('data_output/start_date.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I got this:  KeyError: "Column 'Trip Duration Mean (s)' does not exist!"   
            ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Renzo - Can you test in modified answer?

Comment: I did, and it is bringing this :

KeyError: "Column 'Trip Duration Mean (s)' does not exist!"

Comment: @Renzo - Do you use `**{'Trip Duration Mean (s)':('Trip Duration','mean'), 
                                   'Total Rides':('Bike ID','count')}` ?